# Bigram contains Stopwords in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

i am dealing with a classification problem in weka and using smart 524 stopwords list. 
I am using NGram tokenizer in weka. It filters stop words from unigram correctly but bigram contains stop words i.e. "the east", "the window".

I assumed earlier that weka may first filter all stopwords from the text document and then convert them into unigrams and bigrams however its not what happened out there.

Id there a way to remove stopwords from bigram perhaps i may need another stop word file for bigram ?

would removing stop words from bigram improve classifier performance ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might be using `StringToWordVector` filter to obtain the set of bigrams.
If this is your case, the filter compare the features (in your case the bigrams) against the elements from the stop-list.  If your stop-list is made of single words, there will be no equivalences between any bi-gram and any stopword, so no word will be removed.
If you want to remove stopwords from bi-grams, you have to do it by yourself before applying the `StringToWordVector` filter.
The efficiency of removing stopwords depends on each case, so i recommend to do your own tests.
Francisco

Comment: yes i am using StringToWordVector with unigram + bigram where stopwords are only getting removed from unigram. So i write a seperate program to first preprocess all documents by removing stop words from them and then pass it to weka for applying StringToWordVector